# Convert Map<String, List<String>> to Yaml using YamlBuilder

Tags: groovy, yamlbuilder

i want to convert a json

{"test": "1,2,3,4"}

into yaml of the form:

```
---
test:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  - 4
```

for this i tried to use the following groovy snippet:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText('{"test": "1,2,3,4"}')
println json
def ymlMap = json.collectEntries { k, v -> [k , v.split(', ')] }
def yml = new groovy.yaml.YamlBuilder()
yml ymlMap
println yml.toString()
```

but it prints

```
---
test:
- "1,2,3,4"
```

Any hints how to use yamlbuilder correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

haha, your split-regex contains one space too much:

```
json.collectEntries { k, v -> [k , v.split(',')] }
```

Then it prints:

```
---
test:
- "1"
- "2"
- "3"
- "4"
```

With that space in place, the value is not split and output as-is.